# how to make a listed random output in python?

Tags: python, dice

hey guys i want to create a dice game but the output should be a list
i use this code for non-list ouput

```
import random
f=True
while(f):
    x=random.randint(1,6)
    print(x)
    if(x==6):
        f=False
```

i mean instead if getting

```
1
2
4
6
```

for example 
instead i want to get

```
[1,2,4,6]
```

Comment: So, put the elements in a list. What's your real problem? Post the code you have problems with too.

Comment: What have you tried for getting a list as output? You must create an empty list and then add `x` into that list one by one.

Comment: You literally want to **print** `[1,2,4,6]`?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of printing your value, collect it into a list:

```
# create a new list
numbers = []

f = True
while f:
    x = random.randint(1, 6)

    # instead of printing, append it to the list
    numbers.append(x)

    if x == 6:
        f = False
```

Comment: For code simplicity, please use `break`.....

Comment: sorry the only thing i can use is the sequential algorithm and 'if' and while loop "as it's a homework"

Comment: You really can’t collect things in a list if you are not allowed to collect things in a list…

Comment: i mean i cant use append

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant. It’s a ridiculous restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Put it into a list.

```
import random
f=True
my_list = []
while(f):
    x=random.randint(1,6)
    my_list.append(x)
    if(x==6):
        f=False


>>> print(my_list)
[1, 2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **print** something that looks like a list, and you basically cannot use *anything* that a regular python developer would use to solve this task, well...

```
import random
f=True
first=True
print("[", end="")
while(f):
    x=random.randint(1,6)
    if not first:
        print(",", end="")
    else:
        first = False
    print(x, end="")
    if(x==6):
        f=False
print(']')
```